# angular2 get json data from api and display

Tags: css, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a page where I have to get the json data from an API and display them on the page using Angular2 only. Now the fun part is-

1. The page has some links based on whose criteria the result list
   should be populated onclick.
2. Among the populated results the first 2 elements should be implementing one style next 2 another
   style and the rest should implement another style.

I tried achieving this by doing the following but I am not able to iterate through the ngfor elements(tried @viewchildren but that did not work either) . I am not sure if the implementation is correct as I am new to angular2.

HTML:

```
    <li [class.active]="selectedFilter=='entertainment'" 
    (click)="changeViewFilter('entertainment')">
    <a>
              <div><img src="large.svg"/></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li [class.active]="selectedFilter=='more'"
    (click)="changeViewFilter('other')">
          <a>
              <div><img src="More-large.svg"/></div>
          </a>
        </li>

<ul id= "listid" class="styledclass">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i= index;">
      <li *ngIf=" selectedFilter === ''">(this condition to display all the items when display all items is clicked)
        <div class="opitem">
          <img src="{{ offer.url == '' ? 'image source here' }}">
          <div class="item-info">
            <p><strong>{{ item.title }}</strong></p>
            <p>
              {{ item.info }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
    <li *ngIf="item.category === selectedFilter">(this condition to display items that match the category)
        <div class="opitem">
          <img src="{{ offer.url == '' ? 'image source here' }}">
          <div class="item-info">
            <p><strong>{{ item.title }}</strong></p>
            <p>
              {{ item.info }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
```

Since I do not have an idea of how to fetch data from API- i temporarily created the sample data and created filter in ts like below: 
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'items-list',
  templateUrl: './items-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items-list.component.scss']
})
export class itemsListComponent implements OnInit {

  public selectedFilter = '';
offers = [
    {
      "itemId": 300,
      "title": "sometitle11,
      "info": "This is the Information for 1.",
      "category": "fashion",
    },
    {
      "itemId": 200,
      "title": "sometitle12,
      "info": "This is the Information for 2.",
      "category": "fashion",
    }];

changeViewFilter(currentFilter) {
    this.selectedFilter = currentFilter;
  }
```

**My Question:**
I tried iterating through the generated elements but the css doesn't apply to the list items as desired(That is first four to have one class next four another style class and rest to have another class"). What would the best way of approach to get the json data, store them into arrays and display the items on click of the filter menu and also apply the styles for elements differently.

Comment: If this is CSS styling you could do it with nth-child

Comment: I tried using the nth-child class. but It is not recognizing the child elements generated by the ngfor loop.

Comment: reproduce using a plunker will help us to help you easily